# Trying to understand how to set the location of MySQL log files in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I am having a heck of a time getting this web server to log MySQL errors for me. I just started having issues with MySQL crashing every night and having to restart the service. I am running MySQL on CentOS release 7.6.1810 and the MySQL version is 15.1 (distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB).

I am trying to pinpoint the cause but I am unable to get the log files to generate.

If I go to:

```
/etc/my.cnf
```

then edit it in nano it does not have the `[mysql]` line in the file.
This is where you would add in the general_log stuff.

However, in `/etc/my.cnf.d/` I do have a `mysql-clients.cnf` and a `server.cnf` which do show the `[mysql]` line in the file to add in the logs.

If I add the line in manually to `my.cnf` when I stop the service I cannot restart it.

I get an error:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

The same thing happens if I add the code for the log files in the `server.cnf`.

If I add the code in on the `mysql-clients.cnf` I can stop and start the server with no issues, but nothing is being written to any of the files.

I also created the files and gave them `777` permissions and chown to `mysql:mysql`.

Does anyone have any idea on what I can do to get this logging?

The following lines are what I have been trying to add:

```
[mysqld_safe]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

[mysqld]
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log

general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log = 1

log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: First, please edit your question to specify what version of CentOS you are using. Ditto with MySQL. That said, you should just add those lines to the `/etc/my.cnf` and restart the MySQL service via `sudo service mysqld stop` and then  `sudo service mysqld start`. There is utterly  no way any of those config  options  would ever be needed for the MySQL client; you simply want logging for the MySQL server. Ditto with the chmod of 777 and even the chown stuff. You might be best to just force a reinstall of MySQL and then deal with it that way.

Comment: Jake, 
Thank you for the reply. I feel dumb not using the Sudo command to start mysqld.
I added the code to the my.cnf file and it was able to start using sudo service mysqld start without saying Failed.

I am running into a new issue though - When I try to enable the logs:
`SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';`
using `mysql -u root -p` I am getting an error: `mysql: unknown variable 'log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log` any ideas?

Comment: Happy to hear something worked! As far as the `log_error` setting goes, I would suggest commenting out all that extra stuff you added, starting  MySQL  and then running this command `SHOW VARIABLES;`. That will show you all of the `mysqld` variable options including names and settings. Should help. And I would recommend removing any/all additions you made to client related config like `mysql-clients.cnf` and such. I think now that you know that `sudo` works, the reality is you need to undo the tons of “Hail Mary…” things you tweaked and get back to a stable baseline.

Comment: Remember: You only need to adjust `/etc/my.cnf` and nothing else.

Comment: lol!
Thank you again. I have been banging my head on this for the last 3 days.
I need to talk with someone in the morning about the mysql password. The information I have seems to be incorrect so I am unable to proceed any further tonight.
I did end up going ahead and removing everything I added to the other config files.

Comment: Got everything up and running like it is supposed to!
Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Good to  hear you are in good shape! Put lots of what I posted here as comments as an answer so if the answer was helpful to you, please upbvote  it. And if it was the answer that helped you solve the issue, please check it off as such.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like (good faith) desperation. The reality is you only ever need to edit one config file to do what you have set out to do and that is (typically) the `/etc/my.cnf` file.

With that established, I would recommend you rewind and undo all of the adjustments you made to others files, and start from “[tabula rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa).”

Once you are at a stable state, I recommend logging into MySQL and running this command to check the values of current MySQL server settings:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

That will show you all variable names and settings. Make sure the values you are adjusting are indeed named the way the MySQL install expects them to be named.

Once you confirm those values, set them as you have outlined. Just note that you will *only* ever be changing the `mysqld` settings since those are the MySQL server settings; `mysqld` equates to “MySQL Daemon” which is a classic name for a Linux/Unix server.

Once your `/etc/my.cnf` is set, restart MySQL. But be sure to run it as `sudo` with something like `sudo service mysqld restart`; might be different for MariaDB. After the restart completes, the new settings should be set… Which you can then confirm my logging into MySQL and running that `SHOW VARIABLES;` command again.